# iPhone SKD make the iPod controller appear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, popup, ipod

It's been a while I'm consulting stackoverflow, but this time I didn't find any answer :(

My question is quite simple :)

On an iPhone/iPod touch, play music.
Double tap the home button while the music is playing. You will see appear a popup with the play/pause/next/previous buttons and a volume control.

Do you know if it's possible to make this popup appear programmatically ?
I mean, I would like to add a button in my app that will display the popup, avoiding the user to double tap the home button (most of them doesn't know this shortcut).

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MPMusicPlayerController to control iPod playback, but I think you need to write your own UI. The popup is displayed by a different process (it stays up when you kill your app in the debugger).

Comment: Yes, for the moment i'm writing my own UI. Thanks.